# force user's language preference in the URL - rewriterule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to specify the user's language preference in the URL.
Is it possible to use .htaccess rewrite rule to add a segment to the url, if missing.

URL should normally have this structure

```
mysite.com/directory/en
mysite.com/directory/fr
mysite.com/directory/en/about_us.php
mysite.com/directory/fr/about_us.php
```

If language is missing, I want to automatically transform the url to default to english language.

```
mysite.com/directory                
>> should be transformed to mysite.com/directory/en 

mysite.com/directory/about_us.php   
>> should be transformed to mysite.com/directory/en/about_us.php
```

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# don't redirect 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule !^(fr|en)/ /... something...

# redirect 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

******* *one day later* **************

can someone help me understand exactly what Michael's solution is doing and how to change htaccess if I move to new subdirectory

```
mysite.com/directory                
>> should be transformed to mysite.com/directory/en 

mysite.com/directory/subdirectory/about_us.php   
>> should be transformed to mysite.com/directory/en/subdirectory/about_us.php
```

...

```
# If the URL doesn't match /xx/otherstuff
# !^([a-z]{2}) - exactly two alpha characters not at the beginning of the string
# (.*)$ - store the result found above as $1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([a-z]{2}/)(.*)$

# Rewrite to /en/
# ^(.+)$ - begins with 
# http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 - replace with http://hostname/en
# L = Last Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules.
# R = Redirect Forces an external redirect, optionally with the specified HTTP status    code
# QSA - Query String Append - forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RewriteCond` to look for the 2 letter lang code at the beginning of the URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the URL doesn't match /xx/otherstuff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([a-z]{2}/)(.*)$
# Rewrite to /en/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

If you are using more than 2 character lang codes, like up to 4, use `[a-z]{2,4}` instead.

Comment: Michael - I tried your solution.  I got "http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/examples/MVC/en/index.php?url=index"

Comment: @fnagel Hm this is old. Looking at it, it may be because `REQUEST_URI` includes a leading `/` which is not matched by the condition. Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-z]{2}/)(.*)$` to add the `/` at the start of the pattern.